# Where can I find the source code of JBoss servlet api

Tags: servlets, jboss

I want to debug a class (javax.servlet.http.Cookie) which is in JBoss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.final.jar, but after I downloaded the JBoss source code from github: https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/，I found the source code of that class are not there. Who can tell me where it is?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jbossweb is still NOT migrated to GIT. Its still hosted on the old SVN repos.

What you are looking for is here
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/projects/specs/tags/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final/src/main/java/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.java

The main branch version is 
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossweb/trunk/java/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.java

For all other branches refer
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossweb/branches/

Answer (score 0):

You can find in on Maven Central

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.spec.javax.servlet%7Cjboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec%7C1.0.0.Final%7Cjar

the -sources.jar at the bottom